# What's the type for Dictionary/Map in Idris

Tags: dictionary, idris

How can I define one? I've not found any information about the matter in the documentation. Only about List and Vector.

Comment: Do you want to implement `Map` or use it? There is `Data.SortedMap` in contrib if you want the latter.

Comment: @AntonTrunov, what's the url for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Data.SortedMap`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Data/SortedMap.idr) in the `contrib` package implements finite maps for types that have an `Ord` instance, with the usual interface:

```
data SortedMap : Type -> Type -> Type

empty : Ord k => SortedMap k v
lookup : k -> SortedMap k v -> Maybe v
insert : k -> v -> SortedMap k v -> SortedMap k v
delete : k -> SortedMap k v -> SortedMap k v

fromList : Ord k => List (k, v) -> SortedMap k v
toList : SortedMap k v -> List (k, v)

implementation Functor (SortedMap k)
```

Comment: how have you been able to find that out? where should I look for when I need such  stuff?

Comment: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/tree/master/libs is where I usually look for stuff like this; I don't know if there's any nicer central repository.

Comment: how do you use `contrib`?

Comment: @corazza: start Idris with the `-p contrib` flag, or by specifying it as a dependency in your [package file](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/packages.html)

Comment: @Cactus yep I just remembered the `pkgs` field after that comment haha